# Do native speakers consider particles separate words?

Tags: words, particles

A frequent example used when saying that the definition of 'word' is fluid in Japanese particles, which can be viewed as separate words or affixes. I want to know whether a native speaker would say that, for example, 私は was one word or two.

Comment: This question is amazingly hard to answer, because (1) the equivalent of "word" is nonexistent in Japanese, and (2) the everyday word "word" is, in fact, difficult to find a uniform definition, thus the expected answer would diverge drastically depending on which definition you take.

Comment: The question is not really coherent. How would you ask a Japanese speaker (in Japanese, since that's the only language in which native speakers think about their own language) about "Words"? What word would you use for "word"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a simple and casual question, but it doesn't mean the answer would be likewise. Sometimes a very basic notion in a language turns out to be completely absent in another. One of my favorite examples is ["Framing a question whose answer is an ordinal number"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/11481) on English.SE.

So, conclusion first, if you ask this to native speakers, I'm afraid answers would vary according to personal opinions, because all we can do is to find counterparts from foreign languages we know (that have solid notion of "word") before we decide yes and no. It's very similar to how we sometimes casually say 行った is 過去形 (past tense) or 先生たち is 複数形 (plural), where the analogy goes pretty promising at first, but eventually fail at some point.

The difficulty around the question is twofold:

1. **Word has little practical use in Japanese**
   In word-dividing languages we must have knowledge about what's word and what's not, otherwise we can't write correctly. Naturally we come to have a grasp of "word-ness" even when we don't write. But in Japanese, we don't put spaces in sentence, don't count by word for amount of text, thus don't pay attention to how many words are in a phrase. I guess most people don't have slight thought about it until they're asked.

   [image]
   <sup>(Right: "Come back when you've summarized it succinctly within 20 characters!")</sup>

   Just to be sure, I'm not saying that native speakers cannot perceive noun and particle as separate "units". *Blackboard* is easily divided into two elements, but it's still one word, at least orthographically.
2. **Japanese particle is neither standalone word nor affix**
   One of presuppositions behind the question is that, if something isn't a standalone word (linguists call it *free morpheme*), it must be an affix (*bound morpheme*). This law of excluded middle doesn't hold in Japanese. What we call particle (助詞) in Japanese is established as *[clitic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clitic)*, which is in short, what means like word but sounds like affix. It's a relatively new term, but it doesn't mean that it's a creation by linguists to obfusticate people. Rather, it's something hadn't had name due to its marginal presence in European languages, whereas it abounds in some other parts of world. Japanese language has "real" words and affixes besides particles, so particles are, after all, particles.

   How clitics are processed in space-inserting orthography is complicated and usually tied with etymology: no space (Latin *populus**que***), always spaced (Polish *zaloguj **się***), hyphened (Portuguese *conjuga-**me***), apostrophed (English *I'**ll***), or affected by other factors (French *Je **te** vois* / *Je **t**'aime*). You can see there's no decisive answer whether clitics should fall under word or affix, from the standpoint of grammar as well as writing (well, because they're neither...).

Comment: 右の吹き出しのセリフが句読点入れてぴったり20字なのは偶然！？　ほんで、左の英語の吹き出しはちょうど20語やん～　なんかすごい～

Comment: @chocolate 右は！も入れたら21文字では？（確かに20が一文字分に収まってますが…）あながち偶然でもないかもしれないですけどｗ ちなみに[原作](http://galaxyheavyblow.web.fc2.com/fc2-imageviewer/?aid=1&iid=8)でも一字一句同じ

Comment: あ、「２０」って二文字なのね～ｗｗ　でもすごいーww　英訳が10語にならないか考えたけど無理だったーｗ

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, 私は has two words but other similar expression might not.

I think a part of your confusion comes from what affix means.  In the most basic words, an affix changes meaning of the word to which it is attached.  Consider these example in addition to 私は.  私に、私へ、私が、私を、私と, and etc....Do you see that some of what follows 私 could be easily translated to "to" or "with"?  I believe they are words, though that is not to say all of those can be consideted word.   While the meaning of the phrase changes (from subject to object, In a away), the meaning of 私 remains unchanged so these are not affix. Yet,  there is no direct "word" to describe を or が so they really aren't word in the strictest sense.

You might argue that there is a difference between I and me, which is the difference between some of the examples above. But remember, we dont have a concept of that.  The above example shows how we use the same word to mean I or me.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, they consider them two words. I'm curious to know who would call them affixes.

Comment: They're neither affixes nor full words. They're usually categorized as [clitics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clitic) in linguistic term.

Comment: The question was what do native speakers consider them, not what linguists think of them. :)

Comment: Unlike English speakers, Japanese speakers don't have agreed concept of "word" in their language. This is what makes the question difficult.

Comment: Japanese people do know what words are. I don't think this is that difficult.

Comment: Curiously bold assertion. How would a Japanese speaker say, in Japanese, "Of course I know what words are"?

Comment: @broccoli forest rather than leaving comments that cryptically hint that his answer is wrong, why not try to type up your own answer that will give a further explanation of your stance? Your comments are very confusing to an already befuddling question and will not help anybody else reading this in the future.

Comment: @user11589 I'm thinking over how to salvage this question, but honestly it's like "What's the most popular rice brand in US?"

Comment: @Brian Chandler: 単語とはどういうものか、もちろん知っています。当たり前だのクラッカー！

Comment: 一般的な人のほとんどは、例えば「見てると」が動詞「見る」+接続助詞「て」+補助動詞「いる」+接続助詞「と」の4語から成る、とか、あまりわかってません。学校で日本語の作文/レポート/小論などを数えるときは、普通「語‌​数」でなく「字数」で数え、「語数を数える」という作業はまずしません。日本語を「語」で分解する（品詞分解する）のは、高校の古典の授業でやるく‌​らいだと思います(でもみんなそれをしっかりできるようになるわけではありません)。それから、「語」と「単語」とはまたちょっと違う意味で使われるみたいです。

Comment: でも「見ている」とかいうような（少し）複雑な場合は別ですよね。日本人に「『は』ってどういう意味ですか」と聞いたら（説明の巧劣を別として）少なくとも「は」が１つの孤立した語であることは分かるはずです。元の質問を見失わないように注意しましょう。一般の日本人が「私は」を２つの言語学的要素でできている複合体として認識していることは（少なくとも僕の経験では）言えるはずです。

Comment: I think the reason there seems to be confusion on this point is twofold: 1) Japanese people tend to respond "so da ne, muzukashii ne" whenever presented with a technical(-ish) question about their language by a foreigner, giving the impression that they don't know the answer. 2) There is a difference in the way Japanese people understand segmentation, but it's not irremediably different from the way English-speakers do, and it gets played up too much.

Comment: If you want to know if Language X considers "Y" to be a separate word or not, there's a very, very easy test: see if there's a dictionary entry for it. は、が、に、と、し、へ、etc. etc. etc. all have their own entries. Japanese people consider them separate words. There's no entry for かった or れば or くて because Japanese people don't consider them separate words.

Comment: But, Merriam-Webster has an entry for the pluralizing suffix -s, which is not a word.